# JavaScript equality between objects and strings

Tags: javascript, language-design

According to Firebug console, we have the following in JavaScript:

```
>>> [''] == ''
true
>>> [''] == ['']
false
```

Finding Python to be much more logical here, I'd expect it to be the way round.  Anyway, I can understand the second one — apparently two different objects never compare equal to each other, — but what is the reason for the first to give `true`?  What string would `['', '']` compare equal to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's comparing the string representation of the array on the left to the string on the right.

```
alert(['', ''] == ','); // true

alert([1, 2] == '1,2'); // true
```

Of course you can use the strict comparison operator to avoid this...

```
alert([''] === ''); // false
```

Comment: But why does [''] == [''] and [''] === [''] return false?

Comment: qw3n: because it's not the same object. Think about it like this: `var a=[''], b=['']; a[0]=123; a==b; //false` compared to `var a,b; a=b=['']; a[0]=123; a==b; //true`